# Laravel 4 redirect to intended URL with previous POST data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 it is possible to redirect to an intended URL while using the `withInput()` method, which is a great feature. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following:

I have a form that I want to show to all of my users (whether they're logged in or not). If they try to post this form when not logged in, they will be redirected to the site's login page. After successfully logging in, is it possible to redirect the user to the intended URL **and** POST the information from the original form?

Comment: Since using withInput() just flashes it to your session, it might be possible to work with a reflash() or Session::keep(array('Form1Data', 'Form1DataToo')); ?

Comment: You would have to do something like @L7Lynx said.  It is very difficult to [`POST` with a redirect](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Comment: Probably not. You would be hacking around a bit to get it working. You'd need to somehow repost that data otherwise you won't be able to hit the post route. Reflashing will just keep it in the session longer. I'd just get them to login first.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to send the POST data to the login form as you are doing now using the withInput() method and then add the captured values to hidden inputs within your login form.

If you didn't want the hidden inputs rendered unless the data existed, you could add them dynamically using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since using withInput() just flashes it to your session, it might be possible to work with a `Session::reflash();` or `Session::keep(array('Form1Data', 'Form1DataToo'));` in your login page.